# How to write first negative number in array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am just new in programming so excuse me for this 'easy' question.

I have a array list which have negative and positive numbers. It's in C#. I want to write on console, first negative number in this array list. How can do it? I tried a few things but it's writing all negative numbers or only the last negative number. I can't write the first one. Can anyone help me, please?

Here is my example of code :

```
int[] numbers = new int[] {13, 22, -5, 94, 66, -38, 41, -79, -1, 53};
int[] firstminus = new int[1];    

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] < 0)
        firstminus[0] = numbers[i];
}

Console.WriteLine(firstminus[0]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You can sort the array, then display the first one

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There are a lot of ways to accomplish that, but I think you would learn nothng if someone provides these complete solutions here. It would be better to _show_ what you have tried, so we could spot the mistakes you made.

Comment: Can you provide one of the ways you have tried?  Learning why your approach didn't work may be a valuable experience

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer firstly. But I don't need smallest number, I need the first negative number in the array. If I understood you wrong, sorry

Comment: @nicomp You can use a [magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) to automatically link to the MCVE docs.  Use `[mcve]` in your comment.

Comment: @CPrecius Does "first negative number in an array" mean that the array `{0, 4, -1, 8, -204}` should return `-1` and not `-204`? Or the first negative number you happen to come across in a given array?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(numbers.First(n => n < 0));`

Comment: @itsme86 -- why are you putting an answer in a comment?

Comment: @Hogan Because I don't feel like fleshing it out into a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To correct your attempt add a `break` after you found the number. That will terminate the loop and you'll have the first negative number in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] < 0) 
    {
        firstminus[0] = numbers[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Notice 2 things:

- There is no need for an array `firstminus` - better just have it a simple `int`.
- The loop runs to `10`. This is a **magic number**. Instead run until array's length. Please take the time to read this: [What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/6400526)

So:

```
int firstMinus;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] < 0) 
    {
        firstminus = numbers[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

And last, if you are familiar with linq then just use `.FirstOrDefault` which returns the first item in the collection that matches a predicate (or the `default` of the type if none meet the predicate):

```
var firstMinus = numbers.FirstOrDefault(i => i < 0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that detaily explanation. I understood my fault and I learned news. I am so glad.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, you'll just need to `break` as soon as you find the first negative number. i.e.

```
if (numbers[i] < 0) {
     firstminus[0] = numbers[i];
     break; // terminate the loop
}
```

btw, I'd use an `int` variable instead of constructing an array to store the result.

i.e.

```
int firstminus = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
   if (numbers[i] < 0) {
      firstminus = numbers[i];
      break; // terminate the loop
   }
}
```

---

on another note, the simplest way would be via LINQ:

```
numbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x < 0);
```

Comment: IMHO - this is a  better answer than mine :).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a while loop -- it just makes sense for the problem.

Also -- remember the use case where there is no neg -- you have to handle that too.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] {13, 22, -5, 94, 66, -38, 41, -79, -1, 53};
int index = 0

while (index < numbers.Length & numbers[index] >= 0)
 index++;


if (index < numbers.Length & numbers[index] < 0)
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[index]);
else 
    Console.WriteLing("No neg.");

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Hmm I didn't even think about while loops, thanks a lot

Comment: @CPrecius -- next time think of the poor forgotten `while` loop!  It gets to much competition from foreach and linq!

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers = new int[] {13, 22, -5, 94, 66, -38, 41, -79, -1, 53};

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
        break;
    }     
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

A 'better' solution is to use linq:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 13, 22, -5, 94, 66, -38, 41, -79, -1, 53 };
int[] firstminus = new int[1];
firstminus[0] = numbers.FirstOrDefault(n => n < 0);
```

Update - in response to Gilad Green's comment about performance - great point! When I run the following, I find that the loop actually performs about 1/2 second faster on my box:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Linq method");
        stopWatch.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            LinqMethod(); 
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time: {stopWatch.Elapsed}");
        stopWatch.Reset();

        Console.WriteLine("Loop method");
        stopWatch.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            LoopMethod();
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time: {stopWatch.Elapsed}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void LinqMethod()
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[] { 13, 22, -5, 94, 66, -38, 41, -79, -1, 53 };
        int[] firstminus = new int[1];
        firstminus[0] = numbers.FirstOrDefault(n => n < 0);
    }

    private static void LoopMethod()
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[] { 13, 22, -5, 94, 66, -38, 41, -79, -1, 53 };
        int[] firstminus = new int[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] < 0)
            {
                firstminus[0] = numbers[i];
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd say it's worth explaining why linq is "better" :)

Comment: Yeah good point. Well it avoids a loop, it's less code and it's more 'C#-ish'. It *should* perform better.

Comment: best to add it properly to the answer. (about performance I wouldn't say so.. it probably compiles to very similar code in this case)

Comment: @GiladGreen - You make a *great* point. In fact - on my box the loop runs faster than linq. See updated code above.